# What is the behaviour of writing to a closed OutputStream? Why doesn't my thread terminate?

Tags: android, interrupt, blocking, fileoutputstream

When another thread calls closeConnection(), the thread doesn't reach
`Log.d("Subscriber", "Client thread has ended.");`
Why is this? What is the blocking behaviour of a stream that has been closed? I thought trying to write or flush to it would generate an IOException, but it seems the code is still blocking somewhere. Where? I can't find info on what happens when you interrupt() on a write, or what happens when writing to a closed outputstream.

```
    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            this.interrupt();
            autoCloseOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("Subscriber", "IOException when closing stream. Buffer might not have been flushed to client.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Log.d("Subscriber","Client thread has started.");
        ByteBuffer pgnAndDataBytes=null;
        while(true) {
            try {
                pgnAndDataBytes=fmsByteBufferSubscriberQueue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
            Log.d("Subscriber","Still running thread");
            try {
                autoCloseOutputStream.write(pgnAndDataBytes.array());
                autoCloseOutputStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        Log.d("Subscriber", "Client thread has ended.");

    }
```

The output is as follows:
Still running thread
Still running thread
Still running thread
Close called.

And nothing more. Where is it blocking and why?

Comment: It seems it is blocking in:
autoCloseOutputStream.write(pgnAndDataBytes.array());

How can I leave this blocking method?

Answer (score 0):

Have a volatile boolean shouldClose that you set to true on closeConnect(). Incorporate the boolean into the condition check of the while loop.

```
boolean done = false;
while(!shouldClose && !done) {
    try{
        autoCloseOutputStream.write(pgnAndDataBytes.getInt());
    } catch(BufferUnderflowException bue) {
        final ArrayList<Byte> remainder = new ArrayList<Byte>(3);
        while(!shouldClose && !done) {
            try {
                remainder.add(pgnAndDataBytes.get());
            } catch(BufferUnderflowException ex) {
                autoCloseOutputStream.write(remainder.toArray(new Byte[remainder.size()]);
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't work because it is blocking on: autoCloseOutputStream.write(pgnAndDataBytes.array());

(Output "Still running thread" has stopped)

Comment: It never gets to the condition check of the while loop. If it did, the log would have output "Still running thread", but it doesn't.

Comment: @user2254314 It will with the code I posted. It uses getInt() instead of getArray(). You're trying to flush the entire buffer at once.

Comment: Your solution doesn't make sense to me. If it is the write who blocks, why would I have BufferUnderflowException? I mean what does it matter if I write 4 bytes (an int) or 9 bytes in the array?

Comment: You have no clue, I assume, how large your buffer is. getArray() is *all* bytes in the buffer. getInt() is the next 4. Essentially, my code checks for an interrupt every 4 bytes. The Underflow occurs if the number of bytes is not divisible by 4, as you can't make an int out of less. The loop in catch() writes the remaining bytes (max of 3 bytes.)

Comment: My array is 10 bytes. If it can't write 10 bytes, then I think it won't be able to write 4 either.

Comment: But your code uses a thread interrupt. Mine uses a volatile boolean. Try it. If it doesn't work, feel free to ignore my solution or rate it down. Your code just throws an exception when you try to do an interrupt during a write. When that happens, the interrupt is ignored as though you never called it to begin with and then the loop will just continue. It's not blocking, you're just not breaking out properly.

Comment: It is blocking because otherwise the log would have output:  Log.d("Subscriber","Still running thread");  but that output stops. It will never get to your boolean because it blocks on write.

Comment: Try it or don't. I've given you a solution. It would take 2 minutes to copy, paste, and test. It's up to you. Continue struggling, or test the solutions that you're on this site for to begin with. It's standard to break out of threads with volatile booleans instead of interrupts when possible. The only reason your last line isn't called is *because* you're using an interrupt which stops the execution when it can. It never gets to that line.

Comment: Look the underlying OS file buffer is full so it blocks on write(). I've done:
`pgnAndDataBytes=fmsByteBufferSubscriberQueue.take();
Log.e("Subscriber","was here 1");
autoCloseOutputStream.write(pgnAndDataBytes.array());
Log.e("Subscriber","was here 2");
autoCloseOutputStream.flush();
Log.e("Subscriber","was here 3");
`
And it outputs: "was here 1" only!
This is why I need some kind of interrupt or closeStream operation to have it continue in the loop. Though its stuck whatever I do.

Comment: It seems you can't understand that it will never get to:
while(!shouldClose && !done)
where your boolean is. This is because it's stuck in the loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45502/discussion-between-slynk-and-user2254314)